Unexpected output when trying to divide the difference of two pointers with the size of their type
I came across this C++ snippet:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
  vector<float> f(2);
  float *p1 = f.data(), *p2 = p1 + 1;
  cout << (p2 - p1) / sizeof(float) ;
  return 0;
}

The output which I expected was 0.25, but interestigly enough it says 0.
If i try to cast it into a float and then print it, the output remains 0.
cout << static_cast<float>((p2 - p1) / sizeof(float)) ;

What is happening?
g++ --version gives the following:

g++ (Debian 13.1.0-6) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


Integer division results in an integer. Try static_cast<float>(p2 - p1) / sizeof(float)

What is the actual and underlying problem you want to solve through this pointer arithmetic and division?

float *p1 = f.data(), surprisingly compiles w/o errors and warnigns.

@Someprogrammerdude i came across it on the Cisco c++ essentials certificate module quiz. There wasn't an explanation there why it was zero and I wasn't sure about the output.
